# Why is my AWS KMS decrypt not giving me back the string I just encrypted?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, encryption, base64, amazon-kms

Here is my code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const btoa = require('btoa');

let kms = new AWS.KMS({
    accessKeyId: 'redacted',
    secretAccessKey: 'redacted',
    region: 'us-east-1'
});

let params = {
    KeyId: 'redacted',
    Plaintext: 'abcde'
 };

let encrypted = kms.encrypt(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else {
        let x = {
            CiphertextBlob: data.CiphertextBlob
        };

        kms.decrypt(x, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     console.log(btoa(data.Plaintext));           // successful response
        });
    }
 });
```

I am just trying to encrypt the string `abcde` and then decrypt it, but this is not working. For awhile I was getting `InvalidCipherException`, but now the output of `console.log(btoa(data.Plaintext));` is `YWJjZGU=`.

I cannot fathom what I'm doing wrong here but I suspect it has to do with base64 encoding. I have tried so many variants on this code but cannot deduce the problem. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `btoa` when I should have been using `atob`. I would swear I already tried that, but who can say.

Since I thought `atob` was ASCII to Binary, I can't account for how I'm getting plaintext with a function that's supposed to give binary, but...it worked, so.

**Edit**: Thinking of it as ASCII to Binary is misleading. It's more like "transmission format" to "original content," whatever that content was.

The `KMS.decrypt` method wants a binary string, which is the "original content" here. `KMS.encrypt` base64-encoded the encrypted string for transmission, and `KMS.decrypt` expects it to be coded out of that format before being given as a parameter.